# Find splitting field and irreducible decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I'm trying to  solve the following exercise. I did the first two points( hope they're right), but have no idea on how to solve the last one.

> Let $f(x)= x^8 -x$  in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$.
>
> Find:
>
> - its splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_3$
> - the number of irreducible factors of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$
> - decompose $f$  in irreducible factors over $\mathbb{F}_{81}$.

---

My attempt:

- I write $f=x(x^7-1)$. Now, I know that $x^7-1$ has splitting field $\mathbb{F}_{3^t}$, where $t$ is the smallest number (integer) such that $7|3^t-1$. I find $t=6$, therefore the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is $\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$.
- To find the number of irreducible factors, I compute the 3-cyclotomic cosets modulo 7, which are

$$\mathcal{C_0} = \{0 \}, \mathcal{C_1}=\{ 1,3,2,4,6,5 \}$$
       Therefore, I have two irreducible factors for $x^7-1$, therefore I have $3$ *irreducible factors for $f$*, they are: $$x,x-1,(x-\alpha^1) \cdots (x-\alpha^5)$$ where $\alpha$ is a $7-$th root of unity.

- For the last question, I don't think I should explicitely construct $\mathbb{F}_{81}$. Is there any trick to solve it? I really can't figure it out.

Comment: I just figured out the factorization, when it rang a bell. I searched my old answers (I was looking a factorization of the relevant cyclotomic polynomial over the relevant quadratic field), and found an exact duplicate. Sorry about having to vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Anyway, if something remains unclear, then do comment. We can reopen this, if necessary.